# Why doesn't the rep graph show bounty associated with question?

Tags: feature-request, support

[image]

It seems unlikely something like this would be missed so there must be a reason for it -- or am I overlooking something?

Is there a way to find out which question is associated for the bounty?

Comment: Is that your own reputation tab or someone else's reputation tab? On my own, I can click on the gray bar and see the title of the bounty question under the graph. Perhaps the question has been deleted and you've got <10k?

Comment: @sarnold this is for someone else's rep graph.

Comment: @sarnold The date indicates the bounty went in effect yesterday. It's highly unlikely the question was deleted -- it wouldn't make sense.

Comment: You can't delete questions with bounties anyway.

Answer (score 2):

Have just checked a few examples and this appears to be deliberate - looking at someone else's rep graph, you can't see what question a bounty was placed on, you just see the rep spend.